# Is the iPhone accelerometer accurate/precise enough to track velocity (not displacement)?

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer

I know that, using CoreMotion, I can sample the user acceleration values with userAcceleration (which accounts for g) to get partial vectors x, y, and z for acceleration.

Say I want to integrate that just once. That is, I'm going to use a Riemann Sum (trapezoidal maybe?), taking time intervals into consideration, to try and get ∆velocity from integrated acceleration. **Is the iPhone accelerometer precise and accurate enough (with respect to both acceleration and ∆time between samples) to do this, or is it only for rough and general motions?**